# Copy file to windows from linux using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, smb

I am new bie in the python world so please pardon me for asking very basic question.

Question :- I want to copy file generated dynamically on the local linux machine to windows machine at dir (c:\temp123), so how to do this using python script.

As per my research one option is to do mounting and then go ahead and another option is to use "SMBConnection Class" where no mounting is needed, but not sure whether I need to setup first SMB serevr or what is the exact process for doing it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't mount the location on the Linux machine?

Comment: Thanks for reply...actually after doing research I found that people suggesting to configure SMB and using SMBConnection class so till now not tried with mounting because I thought let's have confirmation from the experts like you before going in either direction.